# Turn text into a link with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

if I had a span element with some text:

`<span>I want this to be a link</span>`

is there a way to use jquery to turn that from `<span>` to `<a>` and add an `href` with my link?

Comment: You can get the text from `innerHTML`, delete the `<span>` and create/insert the `<a>`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Description

You can use jQuery's `replaceWith()` method.

> **replaceWith()** Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content.

#### Sample

```
$("span").replaceWith('<a href="link">link text</a>');
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Answer (score 5):

You could try jQuery's [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) using it's callback function syntax to extract the current content of the span element and put it in the new anchor element.

Put in a (slightly) generic function it would look something like this:

```
function replaceWithAnchor(selector,url) {
   $(selector).replaceWith(function() {
     return $("<a></a>").attr("href",url).append($(this).contents());
   });
}

replaceWithAnchor("span", "http://google.com");
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cSZGr/1/

(Note: you'll presumably want a more specific selector than just "span" or it will replace *all* spans as shown in my demo - although you'll note the individual span content is retained in the resulting anchor elements.)

Of course if you don't need a generic version then just do this:

```
$("span").replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<a></a>").attr("href","http://URL.com").append($(this).contents());
});
```

Before:

```
<span>I want this to be a link</span>
```

After:

```
<a href="http://google.com">I want this to be a link</a>
```

P.S. Another way to do it is with the [`.wrap()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), which wouldn't actually *replace* the span, it would add an anchor element *around* the span. This might be helpful if your span has styles that you don't want to lose or something.

Comment: I like the wrap() idea. The others are unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @Ernest - Yes, I prefer the `.wrap()` plan too, but I included it only as a postscript because the question did explicitly ask about turning a span into an anchor.